# Difference between Auto-Scaling Policies in AWS fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I started exploring fargate in Amazon Web Service and it is working as expected.
Now when I try to apply different auto scaling policy, I couldn't get the difference between ***Step-Scaling*** and ***Target Tracking policy***

***I understand the step scaling policy is :***

We specify MULTIPLE thresholds Along with different responses.

Threshold A - add 1 instance when CPU Utilization is between 40% and 50%

Threshold B - add 2 instances when CPU Utilization is between 50% and 70%

Threshold C - add 3 instances when CPU Utilization is between 70% and 90%

And so on and so on

(i.e) There are multiple thresholds

1) But I couldn't understand how the target tracking policy works?
2) Not sure about the difference between Step scaling and Target Tracking policy

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try and answer your questions.

> 1. But I couldn't understand how the target tracking policy works?

Well, AWS creates the Cloudwatch alarm for you on basis of the target specified by you. It monitors the alarm and in the event of any alarm breach, tries to keep the metric near the target value by scaling in or scaling out. Additionaly, target tracking scaling policy also adjusts to the changes in the metric due to a changing load pattern.

> 2. Not sure about the difference between Step scaling and Target Tracking policy

I'd go for a target tracking policy if I am sure that my scaling metric increases/decreases in proportion of the number of instances in the auto scaling group. On the other hand, if I'd want more fine grained control of the scaling in or scaling out I'd go for step scaling say for example I've a real time websocket application behind a load balancer (with least connection algorithm) and the average CPU utilization suddenly starts jumping over 80, I'd add maybe 3-4 instances so that all new connections get routed to my new instances and the other instances get a breather.

> So if I understand correctly, in step scaling we need to specify the
>   alarm range as I mentioned in the question but in target tracking, we
>   need to specify one target value like 90 percent which indicates that
>   it if the instances has 90 percent of CPU then it spans another one?

Yes that's correct. AWS ECS takes care of spawning another task/instance so that it keeps the metric under check.

> It makes sure it maintains the 90 percent max CPU in all the instances
>   Say if my target value is 90 percent?

No, it doesn't make sure that if your target value is 90 percent, all the instances will be under 90 percent CPU. A target value is usually an average metric over all the instances in your scaling group. You can define your own metrics but that should be compatible with the target tracking policy. You can find more about that here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in step scaling we need to specify the alarm range as I mentioned in the question but in target tracking, we need to specify one target value like 90 percent which indicates that it if the instances has 90 percent of CPU then it spans another one ?

Comment: It makes sure it maintains the 90 percent max CPU in all the instances Say if my target value is 90 percent ?

Comment: If so how does the scaling out happens in target tracking... could you explain that too

Comment: Say we have maximun of 3 instances, If all the instances try to cross 90 percent, How do the 3 AWS react in this case?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, in this case, the average CPU of the auto scaling group will also start going above 90%. If the alarm is configured in such a way that it comes in alarm state if the average CPU for 5-minute data breaches the threshold for two data points, AWS will spawn a task/instance in the scaling group and wait for a fixed amount of time for the alarm to come in OK state otherwise it will spawn more task/instance.

Comment: I agreed your answer, Still one point, Say my maximum number of instances are 3 and all 3 are spawned and all instances reached 90 percents now If I increase the load, Does all the instances will spike above 90 percent?

Comment: If you have set a maximum limit on the number of instances auto scaling group can spawn and it is already at it's max limit then when the alarm triggers, nothing happens and the CPU will remain above 90.

Answer (score 5):

**Difference between Auto-Scaling Policies in AWS Fargate (Step Scaling vs. Target Tracking)**

### Step Scaling

Step scaling policies increase or decrease current capacity based on a set of scaling adjustments (known as step adjustments) that *you specify*. With Step scaling, **you control the scaling adjustments**.

See here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-autoscaling-stepscaling.html

### Target Tracking

With target tracking scaling policies, *Amazon ECS creates and manages* the CloudWatch alarms that trigger the scaling policy and *calculates* the scaling adjustment based on the CloudWatch metric and the target value that you specify. With Target Tracking, **AWS controls the scaling adjustments** automatically based on your targets.

> With target tracking scaling policies, you select a CloudWatch metric
>   and set a target value. *Amazon ECS creates and manages* the CloudWatch
>   alarms that trigger the scaling policy and calculates the scaling
>   adjustment based on the metric and the target value. The scaling policy adds or removes service tasks as required to keep the metric at, or close to, the specified target value.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/service-autoscaling-targettracking.html

For example, if you set your Average CPU Utilization to 90%, Amazon ECS will adjust the number of tasks (starting or stopping tasks) to keep this target.

*Note: This answer has been revised to more effectively target the question in the subject line for the benefit of future readers (instead of catering to the specific concerns of the asker).*

Comment: I already read the documentation, I appreciate much if you could provide me an example

Comment: I expect say if I set the target value for request count as 30 percent how does the target tracking works for scale up and scale down

Comment: For example, with target tracking, Amazon ECS will adjust the number of tasks (starting or stopping tasks) to keep the Request Count target at 30. If you set CPU at 90%, if the load exceeds this target, ECS will scale out to another one. To ensure application availability, the service scales out proportionally to the metric as fast as it can, but scales in more gradually.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in step scaling we need to specify the alarm range as I mentioned in the question but in target tracking, we need to specify one target value like 90 percent which indicates that it if the instances has 90 percent of CPU then it spans another one ?

Comment: It makes sure it maintains the 90 percent max CPU in all the instances Say if my target value is 90 percent ?

Comment: Exactly, if the load goes below 90%, il will scale in to keep this target.

Comment: This target value is dangerous too: If my request count is switched from 89 to 90, then there will be a new node triggered and If it goes down from 90 to 89 then the created node will be destroyed. What happens If it fluctuates between 89 to 89 and 90 to 89?

Comment: You may see gaps between the target value and the actual metric data points. This is because Application Auto Scaling always acts conservatively by rounding up or down when it determines how much capacity to add or remove.

Comment: Say we have maximun of 3 instances, If all the instances try to cross 90 percent, How do the 3 AWS react in this case?

Comment: Target tracking scaling will try to minimize rapid fluctuations so a quick spike on the instances may not trigger a scaling activity; however, it may well will scale out to another task, and you'll have a total of 4.

Comment: Intersting, So If my target value is say 50, then all instances uses only 50 percent of CPU remaining 50 percent are unused

Answer (score -1):

Target Scaling is like asking your financial adviser analyze your budget and make purchase decision based on that.
Step scaling is like asking your financial adviser analyze your actual need and make purchase decision based on that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).